# Positionning of floats, giving start and end points

Tags: floats, clearpage

I am working on a big document (around 150 pages) and I feel the need for more precise positioning of floats than what I am used to: I would like to ensure that a float appears within a specific part of the document. Consider the following example:

```
\section{my float section}
%Start point of where my float is allowed
Some description

\begin{myfloat}[???]
\end{myfloat}

More text
%End point of where my float is allowed
\section{another section}

More text other Section
```

And let us say my goal is that:

1. Whatever happens, my float appears within the float section. It may appear before it is defined.
2. If possible (i.e. without creating a mostly empty page), the float is placed where it is defined
3. The placement may be top, bottom or even separate page, as latex feels is best.

The closest I've come is defining the float at the begining of the section and use
`\afterpage{\clearpage}` at the end of section. However, this does not really satisfy me:

1. Because of afterpage, the text of the other section may appear before the float.
2. The placement of the float is not where I want it, even when it could be used where I would want it defined.

Is there any package or technique that I can use to obtain this?

Thanks for any help

PS: I feel this subject should already have a post, but I was unable to find it.

Comment: It is not clear, what you try to achieve. Most of your problem should be solved by floats positioning options. For example `\|begin{figure}[!htbp]` or ``\|begin{figure}[!htbp]`. The same settings you can use also at new defined float(s).

Comment: also look at `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package which will make a better job than `\afterpage{\clearpage}` or use `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` to make every section a float barrier automatically

Comment: The problem with [!htbp] is that it does not enable best placement given constraints and I believe it does not provide much guarantees either. At first glance, the placeins package seems like exactly what I want! Thanks.

Comment: `[htbp]` is best placement given normal constraints (`!` means "ignore the constraints") so that plus placeins should do what you want I think.